# Jquery $(document).prepend: "TypeError: e is null" inside delegated event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simple line:

```
$(document).prepend('<div>some text</div>');
```

Produces an error from the Jquery library:

```
TypeError: e is null
```

The error is coming from the Jquery file, not my code. My function does not use any variable "e". The Jquery version is 1.9.1. I didn't find any known issues that produce this error, but the line above is the one causing it, since the error does not occur when the line is commented out. I can append elements in other places just fine. The function where the problem line occurs is called from a MouseEnter event handler, if that makes a difference.

Any idea what could be causing this?

If you want more code (irrelevant lines omitted for clarity and brevity):

```
// Create a delegate event handler:
this.protected.$element.on('mouseenter','.'+this.protected.Prefrences.TriggerClass,function(e){base.eMouseEnter(e,this)});


// Called when the user hovers over the tooltip
ATK.ToolTip.prototype.eMouseEnter = function(e, eventThis){
   this.ShowToolTip($(eventThis));   
}


ATK.ToolTip.prototype.ShowToolTip = function($TipElement){
   $(document).prepend('<div>sometext</div>'); // Triggers "TypeError: e is null" ?!
}
```

Comment: "The error is coming from the Jquery file, not my code" -- That means that the error propagated all the way to jQuery. Check the callstack trace in your browser's devtools, and add breakpoints, debug until you find the culprit. Tip: 99.99% of the time it is your code's fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add `div` element to start of `document`, instead of this:

```
$(document).prepend('<div>sometext</div>');
```

try doing:

```
$(document.body).prepend('<div>sometext</div>');
```

Comment: Well that was too easy!